# Update to latest git version 2.2.x in CentOS

Tags: git, centos

The following is the current version.

```
git --version
git version 2.1.0
```

How do I update to latest git version 2.2.x in CentOS.
yum install git says its the latest version on the Linux AMI instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you have a version of git that new is surprising. That isn't packaged officially for CentOS 6 or 7.

CentOS 6 ships with git 1.7.1.

CentOS 7 ships with 1.8.3.1.

To get a newer version of git you'll need to find out where you got your already "new" version of git from and see if they have an update. Amazon could have packaged a newer version themselves and may not have yet updated that package.

With output from `yum info git` of (from the comments):

```
$ yum info git
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Installed Packages
Name : git
Arch : x86_64
Version : 2.1.0
Release : 1.35.amzn1
Size : 22 M
Repo : installed
From repo : amzn-main
Summary : Fast Version Control System
URL : git-scm.com
License : GPLv2
Description : Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
            : unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations
            : and full access to internals.
```

it appears that Amazon have packaged `git` version 2.1 themselves and if `yum update` doesn't get you a newer version then they haven't packaged any version newer then that.

The [release notes](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/latest-release-notes/) page for the `Amazon Linux AMI` seems to agree with that.

Comment: How do I find out which repository provided the current git 2.1 version in the Linux AMI?

Comment: @Rpj The output I requested would be a helpful start. Also `yum info git`.

Comment: _gitpath=$(command -v git); echo "$_gitpath"; rpm -qf "$_gitpath"
/usr/bin/git
git-2.1.0-1.35.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: yum info git
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Installed Packages
Name        : git
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.1.0
Release     : 1.35.amzn1
Size        : 22 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : amzn-main
Summary     : Fast Version Control System
URL         : http://git-scm.com/
License     : GPLv2
Description : Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
            : unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations
            : and full access to internals.
            :

Comment: So it came from the `amzn-main` repository which Amazon provides. If `yum update` doesn't get you a new version of git then they haven't packaged one yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is given in the Documentation of git that for RHEL and CentOS we have to build it from source for the latest version.